# Networking with local devices while using VPN

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, vpn, lan

In my home network, I have Linux Mint 20.3 on my laptop and Android 11. They both use Wireless LAN created by my router. Sometimes when I switch on VPN on either of the device, then I am unable to connect to the other device. For example, if I have a web server running on my laptop, I am unable to access it by typing its IP address on my phone browser.

How can I access my devices on LAN while being connected to VPN for external traffic? I am using Cyberghost VPN

Comment: Your VPN needs to support "split tunnelling". In other words it needs to be able to support bypassing the VPN for particular addresses or programs.

Comment: Apparently you made a bad choice of VPN for what you want to do: https://www.reddit.com/r/CyberGhost/comments/n1tplq/split_tunnelling_on_windows/

Comment: Usually, the local LAN should still be available with a VPN client installed you shouldn't require a split tunnel (with most clients). Did you set it up correctly?